# Keyboard Shortcut, Open New Window [Chrome Extension]

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Chrome extension where you press a keyboard shortcut and the URL will load in a new window, but I can only get the URL to open in the *same* tab.

**script.js**

```
if (window == top) {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', doKeyPress, false); //add the keyboard handler
    }
    var post = "urlhere.com";

    var trigger_key = 85; // u key
    function doKeyPress(e){
        if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == trigger_key) {
            chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: post});
        }
    }
```

**background.html**

```
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    var w = 440;
    var h = 220;
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2); 
    chrome.windows.create({'url': 'redirect.html', 'type': 'popup', 'width': w, 'height': h, 'left': left, 'top': top} , function(window) {
    });
});

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender) {
        chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
    });

  </script>
```

So far, all of the above works, the specific url will display, but in the same tab. Is it possible for it to display a a new (popup) window?
I've tried numerous amounts of coding, but no such luck.

I tried this, but it did not work

```
(window == top) {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', doKeyPress, false); //add the keyboard handler
    }
    var post = "urlhere.com";
    var w = 440;
    var h = 220;
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);  
    var trigger_key = 85; // u key
    function doKeyPress(e){
        if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == trigger_key) {
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.windows.create({'url': 'redirect.html', 'type': 'popup', 'width': w, 'height': h, 'left': left, 'top': top} , function(window) {
    });
});     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show your background.html

Comment: @serg Added - You might remember it from when you helped from before!!

Comment: If you want to open a new window then why not just use your `chrome.windows.create()` code instead of `chrome.tabs.update()` inside background page?

Comment: @serg I was working with example coding, I assumed it was something to do with the JS file. Whoops. But, if I add `chrome.windows.create()` I get nothing, even if I add `chrome.tabs.create()` I get nothing. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @serg Doh! I forgot to remove `sender.tab.id,`, it works after removing that. However, as soon as I add height + width variables it fails.
Working Code = `chrome.windows.create({'url': request.redirect, 'type': 'popup'});});`
Non-Working Code = `chrome.windows.create({'url': request.redirect, 'type': 'popup', 'width': w, 'height': h, 'left': left, 'top': top});});`

So where do I implement the height and width?

Comment: I will look into it in couple hours if nobody else answers...

Comment: Whoops! Forgot the re-add the variables. Fixed it :) Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this function for opening in a new window:

```
function openInNewWindow(url) {
   var newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
   newWindow.focus();
}
```